# group mysql results in nested array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I have a MySQL query like this:

```
SELECT c.id
     , c.company_name
     , b.brand_id
     , b.brand_name 
  FROM companies as c 
  JOIN brands AS b 
    ON c.id = b.company_id;
```

which returns a table like this:

[image: mysql results]

The results are stored in `$items`

I want to be able to use a `foreach` loop to display the results like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><b>adidas plc</b></li>
  <li>adidas</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><b>coca-cola</b></li>
  <li>coke</li>
  <li>dr pepper</li>
  <li>7up</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><b>ebay</b></li>
  <li>Duobam</li>
</ul>
```

How can I accomplish this with just using the above join query? I can do it by first querying the company table and then doing a new query for each on the brand table but with thousands of companies and multiple brands for each its going to cause too many queries.

```
          foreach($items as $item){
            echo '
            <ul>
              <li><b>'.$item['company_name'].'</b></li>
              <li>'.$item['brand_name'].'</li>
            </ul>
            ';
          }
```

Comment: just loop through the result an if the company_name changes close and open `<ul>`

Comment: nevertheless it will/can work. That's the usual way to do things like that. In a loop store the current company_name, in the next loop compare stored with actual one. If different-> make a new header, if the same just output the brand.

Comment: do you have any example code?

Comment: You need to show the PHP you've got so far.  Are you loading the query results? What's the variable name? Etc.

Comment: added current code

Comment: @MikeMeade You've not seen the answer, did you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of doing such things:

```
<?php

$brands = Array (
Array (  'company_name' => 'adidas',
         'brand_name' => 'adidas' ),
Array (  'company_name' => 'coca-cola',
         'brand_name' => 'coke' ),
Array (  'company_name' => 'coca-cola',
         'brand_name' => 'dr pepper' ),
Array (  'company_name' => 'coca-cola',
         'brand_name' => 'sprite' ),
Array (  'company_name' => 'ebay',
         'brand_name' => 'duobam' ),
);


$old_company = "";   // storage for current company_name


foreach($brands as $brand) {
    if($old_company!=$brand['company_name']) {  // if it changed, show it
        if($old_company!='') echo "</ul>";
        echo "<ul><li><b>".$brand['company_name']."</b></li>";
    }
    echo "<li>".$brand['brand_name']."</li>";
    $old_company=$brand['company_name'];  // update company_name
}
echo "</ul>";  // final ul closure

?>
```

Same technique works with tables, table rows, etc...
**NOTE** that the data source *must* be sorted/grouped by company_name!

Comment: i am having problems with <li>'s nested within each other?

Comment: I don't have that in my fiddle. Sure you didn't miss a `/` somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Order the results in company name order and then put the header part of each company group when the returned company name changes.

You could put out the sections using a class. Create a new instance each time the company name changes, having deleted any existing one. You can put out the first and last lines in the constructor and destructor.

```
<?php

$result = $db->query("SELECT c.id,
                                c.company_name,
                                b.brand_id,
                                b.brand_name 
                        FROM companies as c 
                        JOIN brands AS b 
                        ON c.id=b.company_id
                        ORDER BY c.company_name,
                                b.brand_name");
if($result)
{
    $prev_company_name = '';
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        if ($prev_company_name != $row['company_name'])
        {
            if ($prev_company_name != '')
            {
                unset($company_line);
            }
            $prev_company_name = $row['company_name'];
            $company_line = new company_out($row['company_name']);
        }
        $company_line->out_line($row['brand_name'])
    }
    if ($prev_company_name != '')
    {
        unset($company_line);
    }
}


class company_out
{

    public function __CONSTRUCT($company)
    {
        echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li><b>$company</b></li>";
    }

    public function __DESTRUCT()
    {
        echo "</ul>";
    }

    public function out_line($line)
    {
        echo "<li>$line</li>";
    }
}
```